# A software for downloading an online book

Tags: download-manager, ebooks, file-converter

Is there some kind of software that would allow me to download this online book and/or convert it to pdf?

http://ip194097.ntcu.edu.tw/memory/TGB/thak.asp?id=578

Of course I could save each page separately and then merge them into a pdf, but it would take a lot of time, since the book has 451 pages.

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest a web crawler like wget or Offline Explorer
with the right rules, this should  be easy

and even a small batch like

wget "http://ip194097.ntcu.edu.tw/memory/TGB/data/Tbook/TBook1/TBook1_%E9%A0%81%E9%9D%A2_001.png"
.....
wget "http://ip194097.ntcu.edu.tw/memory/TGB/data/Tbook/TBook1/TBook1_%E9%A0%81%E9%9D%A2_451.png"

should be easy to make in minutes with a spreadsheet

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at these previous answers as may be useful:

[Software that takes a webpage and collates information from its internal links](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/81241/software-that-takes-a-webpage-and-collates-information-from-its-internal-links)

[recommends a script and some plugins]

[Looking for software: create, manage, export manuals](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/76766/looking-for-software-create-manage-export-manuals/76775#76775)

[Sphinx, LogicalDoc, etc]